# Need help making a design decision with jQuery tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, jquery-tabs

There will be a list of "plans" that the user has, and I want to be able to click on any of them (separated by divs) and have its information dynamically loaded from the database.

My question is whether I should use a jQuery tab interface and load the content that way, or a button which triggers an ajax call?  Is there any easier/prettier way to do this that I'm not thinking of?

Thank you for any help, it is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many existing solutions online . You can roll your own too . Here are some samples which has many with AJAX content loading . You can either use existing or change then as you need.

http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tabs/ajax.html . You can change .html to your own php,asp ,jsp what ever pages and pass plan id and page can return HTML .

http://webdesignledger.com/tutorials/11-useful-jquery-tab-navigation-solutions

http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/50-nice-clean-css-tab-based-navigation-scripts/

http://justintadlock.com/archives/2007/11/07/how-to-create-tabs-using-jquery

Answer (score 0):

I used the jquery-jvert-tabs plugin for something very similar.  Each tab had its content dynamically loaded and the whole div was called via ajax, it worked pretty well together.

Talking about which one is prettier, it doesn't matter whichever you choose if you just make sure is cohesive with your overall design :)

Answer (score 0):

I would use tabs- no need to have a separate button if the plan name can be the tab name.

Design should almost always focus on usability and it seems like this approach would serve that goal well.

If your list of plans; however, is dynamic or can grow overtime then I would go with a dropdown populated with the list and a button that gets the details or wire up on onchange event and get the data.

The question is a bit vague so maybe if you provided more information we could better help you here.